# Regular Expression confused by use of double and single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this JavaScript (running in Chrome 48.0.2564.103 m):

```
var s1 = 'label1="abc" label2=\'def\' ';
var s2 = 'label1="abc" label2=\'def\' label3="ghi"';
var re = /\b(\w+)\b=(['"]).*?def.*?\2/;

re.exec(s1); // --> ["label2='def'", "label2", "'"]
re.exec(s2); // --> ["label1="abc" label2='def' label3="", "label1", """]
```

The first exec() matches label2, as I intended. However, the second gets confused by the double quote after 'label3=' and matches label1 instead.

I had expected the use of .*? to tell the regular expression to make the match as tightly as possible, but clearly it doesn't always. Is there a way to tighten up my regular expression?

Comment: A simple option can be [`\w+=\S*def\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/cX6zB8/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exclude what was seen as a quote

```
/\b(\w+)\b=(['"])(?:.(?!\2))*def(?:.(?!\2))*.?\2/
```

So the change was replacing your `.*?` with `(?:.(?!\2))*`.

Break down:

- `(?!)` is negative look ahead, non-capturing
- `(?:)` is non-capturing group.
- The last letter right before the closing quote would not match if it's not `def`, need `.?` to fix

This allows you to combine other rules when you want to allow `a='\''` or `a="\""` or further `a="\\\""`:

```
/\b(\w+)\b=(['"])(?:\\\\|\\\2|.(?!\2))*def(?:\\\\|\\\2|.(?!\2))*.?\2/
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker You edited my later part, actually `.*?` is enough, because the look ahead is `\2`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason `s2` gives a different result is that you add a `"` on the right side of the "def" after label2, which allows the pattern to *correctly* match everything between the first and last double quote in the string.

I can only guess that the reason a sparse match (`?`) doesn't have any effect is that at that point the regex engine has already decided to match `"` rather than `'`. Regex does its thing left-to-right after all.

The "simplest" way of solving this is to match only non-quotes, rather than using `.`, between the quotes:

```
var re = /\b(\w+)\b=(['"])[^'"]*def[^'"]*\2/;

re.exec(s1); // --> ["label2='def'", "label2", "'"]
re.exec(s2); // --> ["label2='def'", "label2", "'"]
```

The problem with this is that now you can't put *any* kind of quotes in the value, even if they are perfectly legal:

```
// This won't match because of the " after def
var s2 = 'label1="abc" label2=\'def"\' label3="ghi"'

// This won't match because there's an escaped single quote in the value
var s2 = 'label1="abc" label2=\'def\\\'\' label3="ghi"'
```

But basically, regex isn't made for parsing HTML, so if these limitations are a problem you should look into proper parsing.

Comment: Note: The regex suggested by Diryboy, though different-looking, appears to be practically identical to mine and has all the same limitations.

Comment: No, it also allows matches like `label1="abc'def'ghi"` because it doesn't exclude *all* quotes from the match, just the delimiting ones.

Comment: @Hubro: I chose the other answer only because it is a slightly more complete solution. However, I'll probably use your one as it does the job for the data I'm receiving.

Comment: @TimPietzcker In theory I agree with you, but I tested it and it doesn't work. I'm guessing the regex engine in Chromium 47 replaces references like `\1` with the pattern of group 1, not the match, making this: `(?:.(?!\2))` equivalent to this: `(?:.(?!["']))`

Comment: `label1="abc'def'ghi"` not works because of boundary issue, the later lookup does not match the last letter `i`. I'll update the answer to fix it. You can try here https://regex101.com/r/nC0gQ4/2